# Why did Rails Active Record migration generate COLLATE utf8_bin on varchar columns of mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration

I have running jruby on rails for rails version 3.0.10.  I found out that somehow active record migration generate COLLATE utf8_bin on all the varchar column.
when I do a show create table users:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) not null AUTO_INCREMENT default NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin not null default '',
  `remember_created_at` datetime,
  `sign_in_count` int(11) default 0,
  `current_sign_in_at` datetime,
  `last_sign_in_at` datetime,
  `current_sign_in_ip` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin default NULL,
....
```

Anyone has an idea why and how to turn it off?

Comment: Can you show the table as defined in `db/schema.rb`? Looking at the Rails' source I can't see where it would set this.

Answer (score 5):

The `utf8_bin` collation is used to compare strings in a case sensitive mode, by the binary value of each character. It may depend on your local settings of your database which charset or collation is used. For example for a MySQL database, you can check the collation mode of your MySQL database by the following MySQL command

```
mysql> SELECT COLLATION(VERSION());
+----------------------+
| COLLATION(VERSION()) |
+----------------------+
| utf8_general_ci      |
+----------------------+
```

..or by using this one..

```
mysql> show variables like '%collation%';
+----------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value             |
+----------------------+-------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci   |
| collation_database   | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_server     | latin1_swedish_ci |
+----------------------+-------------------+
```

In your case one of these values should be `utf8_bin`. The general values for the database can be set in your configuration file, probably `my.cnf` for MySQL. In order to create a MySQL table with a specific engine, charset or collation you can use migration options:

```
create_table :users, 
        :options => 'ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci'
        ...
```

According to the documentation, the [table character set and collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-table.html) are MySQL extensions, there are no such things in standard SQL.