# How to specify a collation for a column when creating a model with rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Quick question: **How to specify a collation for a specific column when creating a model with rails?**

I haven't found any option in the rails API doc but I think it's very important to explicit declare a collation for some attributes.

Let's say that the default collation is `utf8_unicode_ci`. But when creating an Users model the password field's collation should be `utf8_bin`.

So, when using rails like this

```
rails g model Users username:string password:string
```

you can't specify password to use `utf8_bin` collation.

Any way to do it?

**EDIT:**
The generated SQL should be something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id`               INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT  COMMENT 'Unique ID',
  `username`         VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL                      COMMENT 'Nick/username',
  `password`         VARCHAR(32) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin           COMMENT 'Encoded password',

  PRIMARY KEY(`id`),
  INDEX(`username`)
);
```

I don't care if you can't do it directly via a command and you have to modify the `db/timestamp_create_users.rb` file. But the point is being able to use the rails migrations.

Comment: Perhaps this can help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907210/why-did-rails-active-record-migration-generate-collate-utf8-bin-on-varchar-colum

Comment: No. My database is set up to use utf8_unicode_ci so that's the default value, but the problem is I want to set *some* columns of *some* tables to use a different collation.
(Also, there's a problem with mysql2 gem with utf8mb4 but that's a different thing)

Comment: Check the very first answer to that question. I think it's your case.

Comment: Hi! No, as I told you before it's not the case because that question is for the whole database. I mean, you are telling me to set the config for the database in my.cfg where I want just the collation of one of the columns to be different to the others.

I don't know if you read the SQL example in the question, but that's not what that answer is doing ;)

Comment: Hmm, I thought rails would have a similar way of setting collation on the column level, sorry about that. See my answer instead.

Answer (score 11):

Sadly it seems that rails does not provide any high level way to set column-level collation so you have to fall back to SQL at least a little. Here's how I did it:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration                                     
  def change                                                                    
    create_table :users do |t|                                                  
      t.string   :password                                                      
    end                                                                         

    reversible do |dir|                                                         
      dir.up {                                                                  
        change_column :users, :password, "VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin"
      }                                                            
    end                                                                         
  end                                                                           
end
```

The `reversible` block is there just to enable rollbacks because rails would not know how to revert `change_column` without the original value.

Then you can check the collation on the mysql cli with:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS;
```

you should see your default collation there - probably utf8_unicode_ci. Then do:

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM users;
```

And there you should see utf8_bin at the password field.

Comment: Wow, that's it's then a big fail of Rails. And added to the thing that mysql2 gem doesn't work with utf8_mb4 because of a bug, I think I'll manage my SQL code manually... so I can have more control, and things will work lol

Comment: Can you describe what you think could go wrong with the standard utf8_unicode_ci collation? But yes, it rather seems ActiveRecord should have a high-level tool for collation manipulation on the column level. I think all major SQL dbs support that so there should be no problem with portability.

Answer (score 2):

Good news,
rails now has collation built into migrations

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string   :password, :collation => :utf8mb4_bin, :comment => "Encoded password"
    end
  end
end
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_column

mysql can tell you the character sets via

```
show character set;
```

Comment: nice it only took 8 years :)